I have a dynamic component, but it won't import any modules such Common and Forms module
I have a component that use a dynamic component to display a child component:
in parent component, the child is declared as such
  @ViewChild('lscRef', { read: ViewContainerRef, static: false }) // Set static: false to ensure availability after view initialization
  lscRef!: ViewContainerRef;

the tempalte is as follows:
<p-dialog [(visible)]="preview" header="Track Preview">
    <ng-template pTemplate="message" let-message>
        <div class="flex flex-column align-items-center w-full gap-3 border-bottom-1 surface-border">
            <div>
                <ng-template #lscRef></ng-template>
            </div> 
              <p-button (click)="next()" [disabled]="currentIndex === track.length - 1">Next</p-button>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</p-dialog>

the load component code is as follows:
loadComponent(): void {
    if (!this.lscRef) return; // Ensure lscRef is available before proceeding

    const item = this.track[this.currentIndex];
    console.log(item)

    this.lscRef.clear();

    const component = this.componentMap[item.type];
    console.log(component)

    if (component) {
      const componentRef = this.lscRef.createComponent(component); // Use 'component' here
      componentRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
      if (componentRef.instance && item.data) {
        console.log(componentRef.instance)
        const deepCopiedData = structuredClone ? structuredClone(item.data) : JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(item.data));

        console.log('Assigning deep-copied data:', deepCopiedData);
  
        componentRef.instance.data = deepCopiedData;      }
    }
  }

The errors I get are :

Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'div' [duplicate]
even though the CommonModule is imported.

Can't bind to ngModel since it isn't a known property of input error
even though the FormsModule is imported.


Template for the child component
<div>
    <p>Decision Question</p>
    <div>{{data?.question}}</div>
    <div *ngIf="hasAnswers; else noAnswers">
        <div *ngFor="let option of data.dq_answers; let j = index" style="display: flex; align-items: center; margin-top: 1rem;">
          <!-- Radio Button -->
          <span class="dial">
            <input
              class="survey-checkbox"
              type="radio"
              [value]="option.content"
              style="margin-right: 0.5rem;"
              disabled
            />
          </span>  
      
          <!-- Answer Text Input -->
          <span>{{ option.content }}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <ng-template #noAnswers>
        <p>No answers available.</p>
      </ng-template>
</div>

Removed the module for the component and declared the component in declaration of the parent module. This is what works for me.
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { ShowTrackRoutingModule } from './show-track-routing.module';
import { ShowTrackComponent } from './show-track.component';
import { ConfirmDialogModule } from 'primeng/confirmdialog';
import { ConfirmationService } from 'primeng/api';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { DialogModule } from 'primeng/dialog';
import { DecisionQuestionComponent } from './decision-question/decision-question.component';
import { PriorityQuestionComponent } from './priority-question/priority-question.component';
import { ParameterQuestionComponent } from './parameter-question/parameter-question.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ShowTrackComponent,
    DecisionQuestionComponent,
    PriorityQuestionComponent,
    ParameterQuestionComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ShowTrackRoutingModule,
    ConfirmDialogModule,
    FormsModule,
    DialogModule,
  ],
  providers: 
  [
    ConfirmationService
  ]
})
export class ShowTrackModule { }

Was going though several stack over flow answers, the one answer said that updating the version from 16 to 18 worked.
So, I tried it and updated the angular version to latest version 19.0.3.

I found out you can't lazy load a dynamic component. With a normal component it started working. The problem was creating a separate module for the component. Added the child component to the parent module. Now, it is working as expected.

You have to provide the Injector instance, which contains all your imports and providers, that is why you are getting the directive errors.
constructor(
  ...    
  private injector: Injector,
  ...    
) {}
...

...
loadComponent(): void {
  ...
  if (component) {
    const componentRef = this.lscRef.createComponent(component, {
      injector: this.injector,
    }); // Use 'component' here
   componentRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    ...
  }
}
...


Thanks for the answer. RuntimeError: NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection context such as a constructor, a factory function, a field initializer, or a function used with runInInjectionContext. This is the error, I get. When I move the Injector to constructor, I again get those import errors.

@Dwarknight my mistake, please check now, please update the new code in the question along with the constructor, what version of angular?

I get the original errors, the angular version is 19.0.3
